# Double question mark, How does it work?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift

I am learning Swift and, as part of the process, trying to figure out what exactly is going on here. I have a custom segue where I want to place my modal view controller dismissing transition. What used to be in objective-c as:

```
UIViewController *sourceViewController = self.sourceViewController;
[sourceViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

`self` is an instance of `UIStoryboardSegue`.
I translated this snippet in Swift as:

```
self.sourceViewController.presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

getting this error from the compiler:

> 'UIViewController?' does not have a member named
>   'dismissViewControllerAnimated'

Now, [by documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/presentingViewController), the `presentingViewController` method looks like this:

```
var presentingViewController: UIViewController? { get }
```

From what I understood by the Swift language documentation, `?` should unwrap the value, if any. In this case the view controller. The unexplained fact is: if I put a double question mark, it compiles and it works:

```
self.sourceViewController.presentingViewController??.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Can someone tell me what I am missing? What should that do?

Comment: waiting for the reason of the -1. I understand it could be a n00b question (as I said: I am **learning**), but I think I formulated it pretty clearly and it's not a specific case nor anything I could find documented.

Comment: what's the declaration of `sourceViewController`?

Comment: @GabrielePetronella I updated the question. it's a property of a UIStoryboardSegue.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The extra `?` required is due `sourceViewController` returning an `AnyObject` instead of a `UIViewController`. This is a flaw in the API conversion from Objective-C (in which such property returns a rather meaningless `id`). It's still an on-going process that started with iOS 8 beta 5, and apparently those API have not been fixed yet.

If you provide an appropriate cast, it will work as expected

```
(self.sourceViewController as UIViewController).presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

---

Now, why do we need an extra `?` when dealing with `AnyObject`?

`AnyObject` can represent any object type, pretty much as `id` does in `Objective-C`. So at compile-time you can invoke any existing method on it, for example `sourceViewController`.

When you do so, it triggers an implicit downcast from `AnyObject` to `UIViewController` and according to the [official guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-XID_30):

> As with all downcasts in Swift, casting from `AnyObject` to a more specific object type is not guaranteed to succeed and therefore returns an optional value

So when you do

```
self.sourceViewController.presentingViewController??
```

it implicitly translates to something like

```
 let source: UIViewController? = self.sourceViewController as? UIViewController
 let presenting: UIViewController? = source?.presentingViewController
```

and that's why you need two `?`: one for resolving the downcast and one for the `presentingViewController`.

Finally, always according to the documentation:

> Of course, if you are certain of the type of the object (and know that it is not nil), you can force the invocation with the as operator.

which is exactly my proposed solution above.

Comment: The explanation is quite clear, but I wonder one thing: the second `?` is then doing what? The first one returns an `AnyObject` unwrapped instance, but the second one? Isn't an optional type required to be allowed to use that operator?

Comment: @NicolaMiotto I think I have a reasonable explanation, see my last update

Comment: Very nice @Gabriele, I think you can save some time turning this code, "let source: UIViewController? = self.sourceViewController as? UIViewController
 let presenting: UIViewController? = source?.presentingViewController", to this, "if let presenting = self.sourceViewController as? UIViewController { }". Handy check of optionals.

Comment: @GeorgeTaskos yep, that could be done, even though that snippet only serves as explanation, so I preferred to be as explicit as possible.