# Cannot downcast from an object conforming to Equatable to AnyObject

Tags: json, swift, protocols, reactive-cocoa

This has been bugging me. I wished to use [Moya](https://github.com/AshFurrow/Moya) + [ReactiveCocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa) and [json-swift](https://github.com/owensd/json-swift).

It does not seem easy without rewriting some of these frameworks as at one point it seems I need to return an AnyObject and yet created some data which conforms to Equatable and hence doesn't allow this.

**Here is a toy Playground-ready example to demonstrate an error message**

```
struct JSValue: Equatable {
    let value:String
}

func ==(lhs: JSValue, rhs: JSValue) -> Bool {
    return (lhs.value == rhs.value)
}

var jsv = JSValue(value: "abc")
var anyValue = jsv as AnyObject
```

The last line errors with this "**Cannot downcast from JSValue to non-@objc protocol type 'AnyObject'**".

I would normally just avoid casting to AnyObject but I have been trying to use [an implementation of JSValue from json-swift](https://github.com/owensd/json-swift/blob/afdf07a0eb0c8cd590211a5a842c7120e2960edc/src/JSValue.swift#L18) and repeat [the pattern described inside Moya's implementation of ReactiveCocoa seen with the usage of tryMap here](https://github.com/AshFurrow/Moya/blob/master/RACSignal%2BMoya.swift#L68). The signature of the callback required by tryMap in the Moya + RACSignal extension expects a return of an AnyObject.

For those that would prefer to see an example than understand the context, here is what I mean:

```
import Foundation

import Moya
import ReactiveCocoa

import JSONLib

/*
let MoyaErrorDomain = "Moya"

public enum MoyaErrorCode: Int {
    case ImageMapping = 0
    case JSONMapping
    case StringMapping
    case StatusCode
    case Data
}
*/

public typealias JSParsingResult = (value: JSValue?, error: Error?)

/// Extension for processing raw NSData generated by network access.
public extension RACSignal {

    /// Maps data received from the signal into a literal JSON type. If the conversion fails, the signal errors.
    public func mapLiteralJSON() -> RACSignal {
        return tryMap({ (object, error) -> AnyObject! in
            var json:AnyObject?
            if let response = object as? MoyaResponse {
                let parsingResult = JSON.parse(response.data)
                json = parsingResult.value! as AnyObject // The same error message as described previously.
            }

            // Note: ignore that I am not handling errors yet...
            /*
            if json == nil && error != nil && error.memory == nil {
                var userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]?
                if object != nil {
                    userInfo = ["data": object]
                }

                error.memory = NSError(domain: MoyaErrorDomain, code: MoyaErrorCode.JSONMapping.toRaw(), userInfo: userInfo)
            }
            */

            return json
        })
    }
}
```

Are there any quick ways around this error message, or is my only choice to use a (1) different method of parsing JSON which does not conform to Equatable, or (2) rewrite Moya to use [the other version of ReactiveCocoa in which tryMap does not return AnyObject](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/swift-development/ReactiveCocoa/Producer.swift#L683), or (3) not using ReactiveCocoa.

It would be really nice to fix this properly by avoiding AnyObject, but at this point I probably lack both the Swift and ReactiveCocoa skills to do so...

On a non-technical level, what are ways around this? Would it be wise to decrease my exposure to unfinished tech?

Comment: What if you make it a class instead of a struct?

Comment: The problem is that I do not control that piece of code. The struct that conforms to Equatable comes from json-swift an abstraction to handle JSON better in Swift.

Comment: Definitely you cannot downcast the struct to 'AnyObject', however it's possible to cast your struct to 'Any' type.

Comment: @Arno: you are correct that altering the Playground example from struct to class makes a difference - though I do not understand why, and that would force me to rewrite a lot of json-swift to initialise it. I don't fully understand the ramifications unfortunately.

Comment: @tikhop: That also works on playground, but yet of course I am stuck because tryMap is expecting AnyObject!

Comment: @Arno: Do you think it would be possible to write some kind of wrapper class which encased the struct inside a class (as I could then cast this to AnyObject.) Is this crazy talk? It feels kind of hacky.

Comment: It works with a class because AnyObject can represent an instance of any class type. (see The Swift Programming Language). In this line: let parsingResult = JSON.parse(response.data);, what is the type that JSON.parse.value! returns? and why do you want to cast this to AnyObject?

Comment: @Arno: The type that JSON.parse returns is JSParsingResult, which is defined by this alias:

public typealias JSParsingResult = (value: JSValue?, error: Error?)

The value which I then get from this is a struct that conforms to the Equatable protocol.

The reason that I then want to return that JSValue is that I wanted a method that would automatically parse JSON for me but return a signal.

Comment: Related, because an answer provides a ***good*** explanation of downcast mechanics: [Double question mark, How does it work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25980596/double-question-mark-how-does-it-work).

Comment: I do now know what a RACSignal is, but I think your only option is to manually create a RacSignal like var json = RACSignal() and then copy the properties from the JSParsingResult

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have hit this problem because you are mixing libraries that were written for Objective-C with those that were written for Swift.

Objective-C `id` maps to `AnyObject`, which can be a reference to any class.

With Swift, if you want a variable that can reference *anything* you need to use `Any`.

Furthermore, with Swift you are encouraged to use structs, where value-type semantic makes sense, for performance reasons. This will no doubt result in structs being used quite frequently within Swift libraries. As a result you can expect significant compatibility issues with Swift libraries and Objective-C libraries.

Comment: "Furthermore, with Swift you are encouraged to use structs for performance reasons." Do you have a citation from Apple on that? Structs have benefits, but I'm not understanding how performance would be the reason to choose them.

Comment: Is there any way of getting past this compatibility issue, or is this totally impossible?

Comment: @RobNapier sorry, that statement was rather vague and a bit sweeping. More correctly, you should use structs (where value-type semantics make sense) for performance reasons. You can see an example of the impact here: http://blog.human-friendly.com/optimising-swift-with-functional-style-50x-speed-boost-from-changing-1-keyword I don't have a citation, but have had that feedback from Apple engineers. The potential for improved performance should be pretty obvious, constant structs are entirely immutable, whereas constant classes are not.

Comment: @olive the only way round this issue is to create your own adapter layer, converting these structs into classes that can then be passed off to the Objective-C framework that required `AnyObject`

Answer (score 1):

My temporary solution until the Swift version of ReactiveCocoa is released was this:

```
public class WrappedStruct<T> {

    let data:T?

    init(data: T?) {
        self.data = data
    }

}
```

I am able to pass that class around as an AnyObject. It's quite a hacky thing to have to do, but it is at least easy to understand.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, I know that it's desirable to use `struct`s instead of proper classes in Swift, but I've found the following to silence the Playground error.

```
class JSValue: Equatable {
    let value:String

    init(value: String) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

func ==(lhs: JSValue, rhs: JSValue) -> Bool {
    return (lhs.value == rhs.value)
}

var jsv = JSValue(value: "abc")
var anyValue = jsv as AnyObject
```

Again, not ideal, but until ReactiveCocoa is fully Swift-ified, it may be your only option. I had to do something similar with the `MoyaResponse` class.